# there are two different solr indexes which are running fine separately, but when i put them together they are not loading, no cores available

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am using solr 8.6.3, i have two  indices, they both works fine separately but, when i put them together in ../solr/data/index1 ../solr/data/index2, they both disappear in solr dashboard.

But the same indexes are working fine together on staging with same container solr 8.6.3.

[image: dashboard after put together in same data directory and restarted]

**what i tried:**
i directly synced staging indexes with dev env but still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Each core has a name which must be unique among all cores on an instance. If you created `index2` by copying `index1`, both will still have the same name. You can change the name in the `core.properties` file in each core's directory.

Comment: Hi Daniel, the cores have different names in core.properties and schema.xml and in all other places,also there are no error message in solr.log

Comment: Did you create both of the cores with the same Solr version? Is this the version you are currently running?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, yes one with v8.6.3 and other with v8.6.2